# View gets invalidated when keyboard opens up

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view

Ok, I realize this is kind of a strange question but I have no idea what is causing it.

I have created a custom view with a square. I've added a few of those to the activity with defining it in the xml of the activity, so everyone of them has a unique ID. Each of them can be manipulated (change the color of the square) with for example the button click. All was working well until I clicked on some EditText I also had defined in my activity. And for some reason OnDraw() of my custom view fired. All of the custom views defined in that activity were updated with the same color.

I have no idea why this fires when I click the EditText. Any EditText. I have tried adding a new one and it is the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/modesList"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<com.zavod404.orglce.ledcontroller.ModeColorsView
    android:id="@+id/experiment"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout. Some of the custom view are on other layouts and they too get updated when I click on whichever EditText.

Comment: Can you share your layout file?

Comment: why do you need to know when the onDraw event to fire?

Comment: I don't want it to fire when I click the EditText, but for some reason it gets executed updating all of the custom views I have defined in my application.

Comment: That might be because the view is invalidated when the soft keyboard comes up.

Comment: Yes, that might be it. I didn't know the view gets invalidated. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Yes you can use ```android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"```  flag for the activity in the manifest. This will prevent the view from resizing and hence it will not be invalidated.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it. Well, the more you know. :D